# A question related to skew symmetric matrix and Orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, orthogonal-matrices, skew-symmetric-matrices

Consider the following problem asked in a masters exam for which I am self studying.

> Write V for the space of $3 \times 3$  skew - symmetric  real matrices.

(A) Show that for $A\in SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ and $M\in V$ , $AMA^t \in V$.

(B) Show that there does not exists $M \in V$ , $M \neq 0$ such that for every $A\in SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ , A . M belongs to span of M.

(Note that $SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ is a subgroup of $GL_3 (\mathbb{R})$ such that any element $x\in SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ consists of all orthogonal matrices with Determinant =1).

I have done (A) part, but I am struck on (B). I thought I should assume that let there exists such a matrix $M \in V$ but I am unable to think of any contradiction.

So, Can you please outline a proof for part (b)?

Comment: In part (b) do you mean to say $AMA^T$ belongs to span of $M$?

Comment: @MatthewPilling No , I mean AM belongs to span of M

Comment: Suppose there is some non$-$zero $M\in V$ such that $AM\in \text{span}(M)$ for all $A\in SO_3(\mathbb{R})$. Since $M$ is a $3\times 3$ skew symmetric matrix, its column space must be contained in two$-$dimensional plane $W$. If you take $A\in SO_3(\mathbb{R})$ as a $90^{\circ}$ proper rotation in $W$, could $AM$ belong to the span of $M$?

Comment: There are some linguistic problems here.  Since $M$ lives in vector space $V$ the span of $M$ $\iff$ $\big\{\alpha M\big\}$ i.e. span of a vector. An easy solution comes from writing $M$ in Polar Form. Since $M$ is singular, this may be useful  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834754/how-to-show-that-the-unitary-matrix-in-a-polar-value-decomposition-a-up-is-uni/ .  It may be the case that column space of M was meant but the question posed asks for span of a single vector, $M$.

Comment: @user8675309 My perspective on this problem assumes $\text{span}(M)$ is meant to represent $\{cM\}_{c\in \mathbb{R}}$. If we assume the first column of $M$ (call it $v$) is a non$-$zero vector in $W,$ then the first column of $AM$ is $Av$ which, by construction, is a rotation of $v$ by $\pi/2$ radians around $W^{\perp}.$ There is no way $Av$ can be a constant multiple of $v$.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I am bit busy. I will get back to it as soon as I can

Comment: @MatthewPilling so we are in agreement.  I like polar form as it gives an easy way to get to a matrix with positive trace, and skew matrices are traceless but it depends on what people want to emphasize

Comment: @MatthewPilling For your 2nd comment  I am unable to understand how the question in last line is related to my question. ( I understood the rest)

Comment: Did you read my second comment directed to @user8675309? I proceeded with a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @MatthewPilling I am really sorry but I am unable to understand it. The problem is that what rotation is wasn't covered in my course? So, I have no clue what a rotation is.So, I am not able to understand how it is a  rotation of v by $\pi /2$ radians around $W$ prependicular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $M$ is skew symmetric if $M^T=-M$. A general skew symmetric 3x3 matrix has only 3 independent entries.

$$M=\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 0 & m_{12} & m_{13} \\
 -m_{12} & 0 & m_{23} \\
 -m_{13} & -m_{23} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$$

You can use the [Rule of Sarrus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_Sarrus) to make sure $\det(M)=0$.

In a more general setting, the determinant of the skew symmetric $nxn$ matrix is
$$\det(M)=\det(M^T)=\det(-M)=(-1)^n\det(M)$$
where we have used some basic properties of determinants. For odd $n$ this means $\det(M)=-\det(M)$ so $\det(M)=0$. This is sometimes called Jacobi's theorem after Carl Gustav Jacobi.

When $\det(M)=0$ the matrix is singular and the dimension of the column space must be less than $n$.

Further, if the 3x3 matrix $M$ above is $\neq \mathbf{0}$ at least one of $(m_{12},m_{13}, m_{23})$ must be nonzero. But as the entries come in pairs over the diagonal, setting one of them to a nonzero value means at least two columns are linearly independent (convince yourself by setting for example $m_{12}=1$ and notice that column 1 and column 2 are now linearly independent). Armed with this knowledge of 3x3 skew symmetric matrices we are ready to continue our adventure

Since $M$ is an odd dimension skew symmetric matrix the determinant is zero and the dimension of its column space $W$ is at most 2 (Jacobi's theorem). But since $M\neq 0$ *and* skew symmetric the dimension of $W$ must be at least 2. Hence the dimension of $W$ is exactly 2. This also means that at least two of the columns are $\neq \mathbf{0}$. We say that the columns of $M$, lets call them $(M_1,M_2,M_3)$, spans $W$.

The subgroup of orthogonal matrices with determinant +1 is called the special orthogonal group, denoted SO(3). Every rotation can be represented uniquely by an orthogonal matrix with unit determinant. We are free to pick ANY $A\in \text{SO(3)}$. Let $A$ be a proper $\frac{\pi}{2}$ rotation ($\det\,A=1)$ *around a vector in the plane perpendicular to one of the nonzero columns* $M_i=v$. The rotated vector $Av$ is clearly not in $W$.

[image: One the columns v and the rotated vector Av]

Hence, with our chosen rotation matrix $A$, at least one of the columns of the product $AM=[AM_1\,AM_2\,AM_3]$ has left $W$ completely. It is impossible for $AM$ to equal $cM$ where $c$ is a constant for this specific choice of $A$.

Comment: Can you please prove that how" the dimension of its column space W is at most 2"? Jacobi's Theorem wasn't covered in my course and I could not find the result "the dimension of its column space W is at most 2" on browser.

Comment: @James "Since M $\neq 0$ is skew symmetric the dimension of column space must be at least 2".Why can't dimension be 1,0? How does being skew symmetric affects it?

Comment: "Let A be a proper π/2 rotation (detA=1) around a vector in the plane perpendicular to one of the nonzero columns $M_i=v$" How you are sure that such a rotation always exists?

Comment: I have elaborated on why the dimension of the column space $W$ is exactly two for a non-zero skew symmetric $(3x3)$-matrix above. According to the problem statement we are free to pick any member of the group SO(3) since the statement needs to be valid for ALL members of SO(3).

Comment: I am unwell and I will not be able to check it now. So, I am awarding you bounty.